# Agent garbage collection in NetLogo

Tags: netlogo

I'm using TSP to illustrate Genetic Algorithms in a class. The students are supposed to write the GA. There is a forever button that will run the GA continually. Whenever a new best path is found it is saved and displayed.

To show how this is supposed to work, I wrote a `greedy-path` procedure. Starting at a random node, it builds a path by taking the shortest link that attaches to an unused node.

Here is the (slightly simplified) forever button procedure that calls `greedy-path.`

```
to continual-greedy-path
  let new-path greedy-path ;; Creates a new path agent
  if [path-length] of new-path < [path-length] of best-path [
    set-new-best-path new-path
    display-best-path
    ]
end
```

Each call to `greedy-path` creates a new `path` agent to store the path. The problem is that I am running out of memory. With the `continual-greedy-path` button on, `count paths` keeps increasing and memory is chewed up rapidly, even though very few better paths are ever found. (There is only one greedy path from any starting point. So the maximum number of new paths is the number of nodes. The problem occurs even when there are only two nodes and no better paths are ever found!)

Are the unused `path` agents not garbage collected at the end of `continual-greedy-path?` Is there something else I'm missing?

The only new agents that are being generated are `paths`. There are no new `nodes` or `edges`.

Thanks.

Update: A bit of experimentation suggests that there is garbage collection. Perhaps it just can't keep up with the rate of new path generation.  But why doesn't the system slow down rather than run out of memory?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like the turtles created by `continual-greedy-path` are not removed, just the variable `new-path`. So, your paths are still present and their `count` increasing, as the `new-turtles` here:

```
globals [ max-x ]

to setup
  ca
  set max-x min-pxcor 
  reset-ticks  
end

to new-max-x
  let new-t new-turtle
  if [xcor] of new-t > max-x [
    set max-x [xcor] of new-t
  ]
end

to-report new-turtle
  let x nobody
  crt 1 [
    set x self
    set xcor random-pxcor
  ]
  report x
end
```

I think the quick fix would be to manually remove those path agents that do not meet your criteria with something like:

```
globals [ max-x max-x-turt]

to setup
  ca
  set max-x min-pxcor 
  set max-x-turt nobody
  reset-ticks  
end

to new-max-x
  let new-t new-turtle
  ifelse [xcor] of new-t > max-x [
    set max-x [xcor] of new-t
    if max-x-turt != nobody [
      ask max-x-turt [
        die
      ]
    ]
    set max-x-turt new-t
  ] [
    ask new-t [
      die
    ]
  ]
end

to-report new-turtle
  let x nobody
  crt 1 [
    set x self
    set xcor random-pxcor
  ]
  report x
end
```

Comment: I forgot about the `die` option. Should have done that. Still becoming accustomed to NetLogo thinking. Thanks.